# additional column in sql results

Tags: mysql

Given the following MySQL statement:

```
SELECT name FROM jobtype_descriptions WHERE id IN (SELECT job_description FROM `table2` WHERE id IN (10684,10580,10583,10582,10581,10579,10576))
```

When executed, it gives me the following result:

[image]

But I want to include the ids job_description column from the inner select statement as the first column. Here's the result of the inner select statement:

[image]

I tried using alias of the second select statement but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your query to be like

```
SELECT t2.id, jtd.name 
FROM jobtype_descriptions jtd
JOIN table2 t2 ON jtd.id = t2.job_description
WHERE t2.id IN (10684,10580,10583,10582,10581,10579,10576);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the column you want by name ie

```
SELECT id, name FROM jobtype_descriptions WHERE id IN (SELECT job_description FROM `table2` WHERE id IN (10684,10580,10583,10582,10581,10579,10576))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT name, id FROM jobtype_descriptions WHERE id IN (SELECT job_description FROM `table2` WHERE id IN (10684,10580,10583,10582,10581,10579,10576))
```

You can generally include any columns you want in a select by referencing them by name. E.g., `SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM ...`

Comment: Thanks! What if I want to add these 10684,10580,10583,10582,10581,10579,10576 as a column also?